# NuGet with MSBuild Trying to locate the package.config in VS IDE folder

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I have a solution running on VS 2017 15.7.4 on Windows 7 and works on 6 machines.

On this new machine (same like the others), I am getting the following when I am trying to compile:

```
The command ""C:\Projects\MySolution\Source\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\Projects\MySolution\Source\ "" exited with code 1

Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\packages.config'.
```

- We tried showing detailed build log, but that wasn't helpful
- We rebuilt the machine and same error persisted.

This is a corporate machine with local admin right user account. I am suspecting that the local admin rights might not be implemented properly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of investigation, it turned out that the project name is the problem.

The project name (and the namespace) are as follow: MyCompany.MyProject.**CMD**

(CMD is actually real).

This project was compiling for ages on all machines, however, it didn't do on this particular machine.

- We deleted the whole folder structure and recreated it and even formatted the machine.
- We tried creating a new project from scratch and calling it the same name - Didn't compile
- We tried creating a new project from scratch and called it a different name - Worked!

So solution was changing the project name to MyCompany.MyProject.**SomethingElse** sorted out the problem. I didn't add CMD as part of the project name, but I will never do and I will pass this to my kids as well.

I didn't want to investigate why it didn't work but CMD resembles the name of the Windows console, would that be the reason? I don't care to know.

Answer (score 0):

> NuGet with MSBuild Trying to locate the package.config in VS IDE
>   folder

Please try to give the full path to the packages.config file:

```
"C:\Projects\MySolution\Source\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "<YourProjectPath>\packages.config" -source "C:\Projects\MySolution\Source\"
```